# why system/connect web services return nothing in drupal 7?

Tags: services, 8

I have Drupal 7 with web services activated, but the `system/connect` resource returns a 404 Controller Not Found response. I was trying the user resource, and it works correctly. I tried using the following URL in my browser window, which does a HTTP GET:

```
https://localhost/drupal/x_login/system/connect
```

where x_login is the endpoint.

Comment: You should post more information in your question such as the http request and response headers. Are you trying GET when it is supposed to be a POST? Returning nothing sounds like you have custom code doing something weird. If the controller isn't enabled, you'll get a 404. If you're not authorized, a 403.

Comment: The answer is a blank page, and the headers show the next error: 404 Not found: Could not find the controller

Comment: Are you doing a GET or a POST?

Comment: I am making the request by pasting the address of the service in the browser url, and in the headers of the request refers as request method "GET"

Answer (score 0):

The services module allows a resource to define the following "things":

1. Operations: provide 5 different verbs

   - retrieve: Make a GET request based on the resource name and an identifier i.e. `GET /endpoint/user/ID`
   - index: Make a GET request based on the resource name to get a list of resources i.e. `GET /endpoint/user`
   - update: Make a PUT request to a resource name and an identifier i.e. `PUT /endpoint/user/ID`
   - create: Make an idempotent POST request to a resource name to create a new resource i.e. `POST /endpoint/user`
   - delete: Make a DELETE request to remove a resource by identifier i.e. `DELETE /endpoint/user/ID`
2. Actions: Allows to make a custom POST request to a resource. This is used for login, logout, etc... These are *never* GET.
3. Targeted Actions: Allows to make a custom POST request to a resource + identifier. This is used for making hierarchical resources.
4. Relationships: Allows to make a custom GET request to a resource + identifier. This is used for make hierarchical requests for things like group membership.

The `system/connect` resource is defined as an "action" above. This means that you must make a POST request instead of a GET request. And it may require a CSRF Token.

```
POST /login_x/system/connect HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json
Accept: application/json
X-CSRF-Token: 'TOKEN'
```